# Resize a specific width div in mobile phone

Tags: html, css, indexing, mobile, position

I have a background-image (size: contain) and a div (position: absolute).

The main issue is that when I change the screen size (mobile size), the box is positioned on the left and it doesn't remain fixed in the place where it is supposed to stay. How can I achieve this or is there another way to do it and having the same result using mobile/laptop? My code for the content is as follows:

```css
body{
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0;
}
           
#fase_0 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/FJxBokN.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}

.disclaimer {
    position:absolute;
    right:33%; top:9%; 
    width:420px; height:200px; 
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left; 
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    font-family: "DejaVu Serif";
}
```

```html
<div id="fase_0">        
        </div>

<div class="disclaimer">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur.
        </div>
```

Here the codepen link: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/clemente-esposito/pen/gOzmwLB?editors=1100)

Comment: Look into [Using Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: So, should I write something like this? '@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .disclaimer {
    width: 100%;
    float: none
  }
}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to have your code like this:

```css
:root {
  --width: 1vw;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#fase_0 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/FJxBokN.png);
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  position: absolute;
}

.disclaimer {
  position: relative;
  width: 36%;
  height: calc(var(--width)*653*1920/94800);
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  font-family: "DejaVu Serif";
  margin: 5% auto 0;
  padding-left: 4%;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  #fase_0 {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .disclaimer {
    width: 70%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-top: 12.5%;
    padding-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body translate="no">
  <div id="fase_0">
    <div class="disclaimer">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
      accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
      magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
      Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum
      qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This would only work if the "#fase_0" is equal to the width of the window; if it's not you'll have a bit more problem but that could still be achievable via JS, but not pure CSS as I did, now.

If you want that you can tell me and I'll edit my message to what you want.

P.S. Do  not trust the snippet but use the code manually in an HTML file

**EDIT 1:** Fixing the snippet.

**EDIT 2:** Adding the JS code for no full-width containers:

```js
function centreAlign() {
  let a = document.getElementById("fase_0").getBoundingClientRect().width / 100;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--width", a + "px");
}
centreAlign()
```

```css
:root {
  --width: 1vw;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#fase_0 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/FJxBokN.png);
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  position: absolute;
}

.disclaimer {
  position: relative;
  width: 36%;
  height: calc(var(--width)*653*1920/94800);
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  font-family: "DejaVu Serif";
  margin: 5% auto 0;
  padding-left: 4%;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  #fase_0 {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .disclaimer {
    width: 70%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-top: 12.5%;
    padding-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body translate="no">
  <div id="fase_0">
    <div class="disclaimer">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
      accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
      magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
      Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum
      qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

With this JS code, you can run the function *centreAlign* to, well, centre align the disclaimer.

Comment: Than you so much. Your help has been vital! Unfortunately, "#fase_0" is not equal to the width of the window. Could you please make it achievable via JS? :(

Comment: @Prest89 The JS is added as the second edit

Comment: Glad to help, if you'd like my services, you always can upvote my solution or select it as the best answer ;)